# how to pass multiple parameters from a main report to a subreport to be used in the query

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have a main report that uses 8 different parameters and those parameters are used in a stored procedure that creates several categories with overall values for the group.  I select the category field in the output and use that as my parameter to pass to the subreport and select the data from a sales table but i need to go further and use the other 8 parameters values from the main report to further select out the data from the table. how can i pass the other parameters from the main report using the category field if those parameters are not part of the output data in the main report.  I also tried to add those field to the main report and then hide them and trying to use those to pass the value to the subreport it give me an error that the i am trying to populate a parameter that is not defined in the report.

Comment: Are you trying to map the Parameters from the main report to the Parameters of the subreport? You can use the function `[Fx]` button and choose the main report's parameters instead of using a field.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.